# Selenium to automate clicking a tab using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am using Selenium with Python to webscrape a page which includes JavaScript.
The racecourse result tabs towards the top of the page eg "Ludlow","Dundalk" are manually clickable but do not have any obvious hyperlinks attached to them.
...
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/A38/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
# Navigate to the application home page
driver.get("https://www.sportinglife.com/racing/results/2020-11-23")
```

...

This works so far. I have used BeautifulSoup to find the label names of the NewGenericTabs eg "Ludlow","Dundalk" etc. However, the following code, to attempt to automate clicking a tab, times out each time.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Ludlow"))).click()
```

Would welcome any help.

Answer (score 1):

The [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) aren't `<a>` tags but `<span>` tags so `By.LINK_TEXT` wouldn't work.

To click on the desired elements you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *Ludlow*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.sportinglife.com/racing/results/2020-11-23")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@mode='primary']"))).click()
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-test-id='generic-tab' and text()='Ludlow']").click()
  ```
- *Dundalk*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.sportinglife.com/racing/results/2020-11-23") 
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@mode='primary']"))).click()  
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-test-id='generic-tab' and text()='Dundalk']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the elements you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *Ludlow*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.sportinglife.com/racing/results/2020-11-23")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@mode='primary']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-test-id='generic-tab' and text()='Ludlow']"))).click()
  ```
- *Dundalk*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.sportinglife.com/racing/results/2020-11-23") 
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@mode='primary']"))).click()  
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-test-id='generic-tab' and text()='Dundalk']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you. Selenium has now tried to click the tab but there is an error message: ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <span data-test-id="generic-tab" class="NewGenericTabs__Tab-mpmc8b-2 fmDZew">...</span> is not clickable at point (576, 447). Other element would receive the click: <div height="925" class="sc-VigVT eLZFEy qc-cmp-cleanslate">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)

Comment: @user25236 Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thank you. The first options worked individually but if I combined them sequentially in a script then it stopped at the Ludlow page and a timeout error was given (presumably trying for the Dundalk page). The second options did not work at all and gave a Chrome not reachable error.

Comment: @user25236 Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement please? StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Thank you for your great help so far. My original question was " code, to attempt to automate clicking a tab". So far, the answer only works for clicking the first tab chosen and not any others.